# unknown_cost_value

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im using ROS navigation package, during setting navigation parameters I have seen some used unknown_cost_value parameters by setting 0. I understood by setting it 0 it means robot should assume unknown celss as free, but I wonder what is the general tendency ? Should I set it 0 (FREE_SPACE) or LETHAL_OBSTACLE = 254 or NO_INFORMATION = 255 ? Isn't it awkward if I set unknown_cost_value to NO_INFORMATION=255 ?(why they didnt already set it to 255?)

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217360/unknown_cost_value/) by [nightblue](https://answers.ros.org/users/23339/nightblue/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-09-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is ambiguous. The values you quote in the second part of the question are the conventions for costmaps, but you don't specify who the "some" is that is using 0.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2015-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0